# Difference between system("echo $PATH") in R and echo $PATH in the terminal

Tags: r, ubuntu-12.04

I want to execute an external program from within *R*, and I added the directory path of the executable to ~/.bashrc. When I type `echo $PATH` in the terminal, everything looks fine, but when I execute `system("echo $PATH")` or `Sys.getenv("PATH")` in *R*, a lot of paths are missing. Can someone explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Does the problem persist if you put the relevant path modifications in .profile instead of .bashrc?

Comment: @Dason I just tried and it persists.

Comment: did you do a system restart after modifying .profile?  I know there are ways to get it to load without that but I always forget them and a restart is the easiest.

Comment: @Dason I used `source ~/.profile` in the console and it seemed to work when inspecting `echo $PATH` afterwards

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `/etc/bash.bashrc` instead?  Also make sure that `system()` treats this as login shell and does full initialization.  Worst case, place a script in, say, `/usr/local/bin` and *set `PATH` in the script*.